# jquery mask output

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery masked textbox which has a mask:

```
$("#txthtml").mask("99/99/9999");
```

When I check the output, it has the '/' in its value. Is there an easy way to get only what the user entered and nothing else? So if text box read `01/01/1990` I want `01011990` .

Same thing if I have a phone number mask, how can I get the user input only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript can replace the `/` characters with an empty string: `yourDateString.replace(/\//g, "")`

Comment: Example for phone `(123) 456-7890`, not sure about the space?

Comment: "(123) 456-7890".replace(/[\-\\(\\) ]/g, "") removes parentheses, spaces and hyphens in the phone number.

Comment: This is JavaScript, not C# or VB.  However, you could use whatever regex replacement methods C# and VB provide and use this regex or at least a similar one based on it.  I can't help you with that as I don't do C# or VB.

Comment: thanks. I was leaning towards string modification as well but wanted to make sure if something like this might have been built in :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp to strip the '/' characters, or do split/join:

```
"01/01/1990".split("/").join("");
```

Comment: That's a very silly way to accomplish `'01/01/1990'.replace(/\//g, '')`.

Comment: @Matt Ball : if you say so... don't know why it's silly. It's just as clear, not incredibly roundabout, and isn't worse in performance (in fact, can be faster: http://jsperf.com/regex-replace-vs-split-join).

Comment: As that jsperf link shows, it's a tiny bit faster in FF 3.6, but **97%** slower in Chrome.

Comment: @Matt Ball, fair enough about the speed, I read the figures the other way around.